# I'm trying to make this slide-content javascript functions but something is not working right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make the functions in javascript slide the content (move the position of it) related to which logo/button i click on, on the buttom of the content slide. Here is the HTML code:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".clientLogo");
var wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");

var activeLink = 0;
// event listeners
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

  var link = links[i];

  link.addEventListener('click', setClickedItem, false);
  //item for the active link
  link.itemID = i;
}
//set first item as active
links[activeLink].classList.add("activeClient");

function setClickedItem(e) {
  removeActiveLinks();

  var clickedLink = e.target;
  activeLink = clickedLink.itemID;

  changePosition(clickedLink);
}

function removeActiveLinks() {
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].classList.remove("activeClient");
  }

}

// changing the slider position 
function changePosition(link) {

  var position = link.getAttribute("data-pos");

  var translateValue = "translate3d(" + position + ", 0px, 0)";
  wrapper.style[transformProperty] = translateValue;

  link.classList.add("activeClient");
}
//transforms
var transforms = ["transform",
                  "msTransform",
                  "webkitTransform",
                  "mozTransform",
                  "oTransform"
                 ];
var transformProperty = getSupportedPropertyName(transforms);

function getSupportedPropertyName(properties) {
  for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
    if (typeof document.body.style[properties[i]] != "undefined") {
      return properties[i];
    }

  }
  return null;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h3 class="about" id="clients">Clients</h3> 
  <div class="client-controls">
    <div class="client-control-next">
      <img src="images/next.png">
    </div>
    <div class="client-control-prev">
      <img src="images/prev.png" </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentContainer">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="itemOne" class="clientUnit" data-pos="0px">
        <div class="client-face">
          <img src="images/face1.png" alt="client-face" class="client-avatar">
          <br>
          <strong class="client-name">Charles Francis</strong>
          <em class="client-title">Director of Development, <br>Megathrone International Corp.</em>
        </div>

        <div class="client-content">
          <p>"<strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</strong>, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam magna ipsum, cursus non lectus imperdiet, commodo tincidunt metus. Donec commodo tincidunt laoreet. Praesent at ornare diam. Cras sodales dapibus velit, non gravida
            justo dignissim in. Nullam ac lobortis nibh. Ut tincidunt lacus velit, sed venenatis neque bibendum ut."</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="itemTwo" class="clientUnit" data-pos="-800px">
        <div class="client-face">
          <img src="images/face2.png" alt="client-face" class="client-avatar">
          <br>
          <strong class="client-name">Scott Summers</strong>
          <em class="client-title">Regional Director, <br>Therasite United Int.</em>
        </div>

        <div class="client-content">
          <p>"<strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</strong>, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam magna ipsum, cursus non lectus imperdiet, commodo tincidunt metus. Donec commodo tincidunt laoreet. Praesent at ornare diam. Cras sodales dapibus velit, non gravida
            justo dignissim in. Nullam ac lobortis nibh. Ut tincidunt lacus velit, sed venenatis neque bibendum ut."</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="itemThree" class="clientUnit" data-pos="-1600px">
        <div class="client-face">
          <img src="images/face3.png" alt="client-face" class="client-avatar">
          <br>
          <strong class="client-name">Henry Philip</strong>
          <em class="client-title">Design Team Leader, <br>WeMakeItForYou CO</em>
        </div>

        <div class="client-content">
          <p>"<strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</strong>, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam magna ipsum, cursus non lectus imperdiet, commodo tincidunt metus. Donec commodo tincidunt laoreet. Praesent at ornare diam. Cras sodales dapibus velit, non gravida
            justo dignissim in. Nullam ac lobortis nibh. Ut tincidunt lacus velit, sed venenatis neque bibendum ut."</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="itemFour" class="clientUnit" data-pos="-2400px">
        <div class="client-face">
          <img src="images/face4.png" alt="client-face" class="client-avatar">
          <br>
          <strong class="client-name">Cecilia Reyes</strong>
          <em class="client-title">General Manager,<br>Graudia Bentmart</em>
        </div>

        <div class="client-content">
          <p>"<strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</strong>, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam magna ipsum, cursus non lectus imperdiet, commodo tincidunt metus. Donec commodo tincidunt laoreet. Praesent at ornare diam. Cras sodales dapibus velit, non gravida
            justo dignissim in. Nullam ac lobortis nibh. Ut tincidunt lacus velit, sed venenatis neque bibendum ut."</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="client-logos">
    <div class="clientLogo" style="background-image: url('images/logo4.jpg');"></div>
    <div class="clientLogo" style="background-image: url('images/logo2.png');"></div>
    <div class="clientLogo" style="background-image: url('images/logo3.jpg');"></div>
    <div class="clientLogo" style="background-image: url('images/logo1.png');"></div>

</section>
```

Do you guys see any mistakes, or have any suggestions ? The activeClient class is moving on click(and working fine) but the content is not sliding(changing positions), and i cannot understand why yet. Do you guys need the css code too? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it, it looks like I used data-pos in the wrong section. (silly me). I had to use it in the logos section, Thanks.